# Syntax Error: insert "Dimension" to complete type argument

Tags: java

This is an abstract class to store and give data. It's part of a larger project with multilevel inheritance.

```
abstract class Account 
{
    String cust_name;
    double acc_no;
    void putdata(String cust_name,double acc_no)
    {
        this.cust_name=cust_name;
        this.acc_no=acc_no;
    }
    public static Pair<double, String> getData()
    {
        return new Pair<double, String>(acc_no, cust_name);
    }
}
```

The error is in line 11 and 13

Comment: Use `public static Pair<Double, String> getData()`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert Dimensions to complete Expression/ReferenceType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885463/insert-dimensions-to-complete-expression-referencetype)

Comment: Didn't work. Both the soln.